# Saving the ArrayList entries

Tags: java, arraylist

Firstly here is my code.

postit.java file

```
package postit;

import java.util.Scanner;

class Postit {
  public static Scanner menu = new Scanner(System.in);
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int MenuOption = 0;

    NewStorage G = new NewStorage();    // Case 1 Object

    while(MenuOption != 3){

        System.out.println(

                "\n--------Note System-------\n" +
                        "----------------------------\n" +
                        "1.   Create a Note \n" +
                        "2.   View Notes \n" +
                        "3.   Close Program\n" +
                        "----------------------------\n");

        MenuOption = menu.nextInt();
        menu.nextLine();

        switch (MenuOption) {

            case 1:

                G.printinfo();
                G.Notestore();

                break;

            case 2:

                G.viewNotes();
                G.printNotes();
                break;

            case 3:

                System.out.println("Program is closing");
                System.exit(0);

                break;

            default:

                System.out.println("Invalid choice.");

                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

NewStorage.java file

```
package postit;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

class NewStorage  {

    ArrayList<Note> NoteArray = new ArrayList<Note>(20);

    public void printinfo() {
        System.out.println("--- Fill note here  ---");
    }

    public void Notestore() {

        System.out.println("Enter the note ID you wish to attach the note with\n\n");
        String inputIDnote = Postit.menu.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter your note\n\n");
        String noteDescription = Postit.menu.nextLine();
        NoteArray.add(new Note(inputIDnote, noteDescription));
    }

    public void viewNotes() {

        System.out.println("Please enter the number of the note you wish to view.");
        int count = 0;

        for (int i = 0 ; i < NoteArray.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println((count++) + ": "  + NoteArray.get(i).inputIDnote);
        }
    }

    public void printNotes(){

        int count = Postit.menu.nextInt();
        Postit.menu.nextLine();

        System.out.println(count + " " + NoteArray.get(count));
    }
}
```

note.java file

```
package postit;

class Note {

    String inputIDnote;
    String noteDescription;
    public Note(String inputIDnote, String noteDescription) {
        this.inputIDnote = inputIDnote;
        this.noteDescription = noteDescription;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ID: " + inputIDnote + " \n\nDescription: " + noteDescription;
    }

}
```

So forgive me as I am learning how to write Java so this is one of my first programs, so if you think its badly written then you know why.

As you can see the program can ask the user if they would like to create a note which takes an ID and note itself. Then the user can view the notes created by choosing the number next to the listed note ID's. So when I close the program obviously the ArrayList is wiped. Is there a way to save the notes within the array list even after the program has closed? As I would like to implement an edit feature later so it would be a useful thing to have.

Comment: Now you need to learn about `File`, `FileWriter`/`FileReader` or `BufferedReader`/`BufferedWriter`.  He's always got nice tutorials. https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-write-to-file-in-java-bufferedwriter-example/

Comment: I think you should create database for saving the array and from there u can access the array for edit or delete from array.

Comment: ok ill look into it thanks

Comment: He's LEARNING Java.  Working with files is the next step.

Comment: Read about persistence. Probably file based is easiest, or relational database.